# Using Geocoder, is there a way to save out the street name, city and zip to seperate columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I'm in the process of switching my app to use geocoder.  In my places table I have columns for address, lat, lng, street_address, city & zip.  Using geocoder I'm happily able to fill lat, lng & address columns after validation with with the following in my places model

```
attr_accessible :address, :lat, :lng    
geocoded_by :address, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lng
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
```

Is there a way to also have geocoder add the street name, city and zip to three other, separate columns?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm still newish to rails so I missed this at first, but hope this helps someone else.

in my model

```
geocoded_by :address  do |obj,results|
  if geo = results.first
    obj.city    = geo.city
    obj.lat = geo.latitude
    obj.lng = geo.longitude
    obj.zip = geo.postal_code
    obj.state = geo.state
    obj.country = geo.country_code
  end
end
```

and in my view

```
 @tonic.address = params[:address]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `geocoded_by` could also take a block